# Use Javascript to scan a local directory and then update an Anchor tag with the "latest" file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, pdf

I'm trying to create a simple HTML page that will basically, load up some javascript, and check my direction (../Files)
the Files folder contains

```
file_001.txt
file_002.txt
file_003.txt
```

I then want javascript to use the latest one (file_003.txt), and update a anchor tag with the id of "file_download".

Would anyone by any chance have an idea how to do this? 
The reason is, lets say I have a terms and conditions PDF file that is T&C_001.pdf and download the line a new terms and conditions is released. so we keep the T&C_001.pdf for any old records and we upload T&C_002.pdf. Now this will not need any HTML knowledge or even Javascript. The owner of the site would just need to add a new file with 002 on the end.

Comment: This needs to be done server side. And not with javascript, unless you use node.js for your server.

Comment: so for instant, I would do this with MVC asp.net c#?

Answer (score 1):

though, not fully accurate, you could try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getLatest(location, filename, ext, readyCallback, index) {
    var tgIndex = typeof index === 'undefined' ? 1 : index;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: location + '/' + filename + '-' + index + '.' + ext,
        success: function() {
            getLatest(location, filename, ext, readyCallback, tgIndex + 1);
        },
        error: function() {
            if (tgIndex > 1) {
                readyCallback(location + '/' + filename + '-' + (tgIndex-1) + '.txt');
                return;
            }
            readyCallback();
        }
    });
}
getLatest('linkToSite', 'file', 'txt', function(filename) {
    if (typeof filename === 'undefined') {
        alert('No file found on the location');
    }
    // do something with returned filename
});
</script>
```

which would try to check if the file is there, when not the previous index was the latest one. If the first one fails, there is no file on the specified location

This reply doesn't add formatting, and rather expects the files as:
 - file-1.txt, file-2.txt, ...

this example assumes jquery :)

a fiddle of it you can find here

http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/JL5Su/