# Call multiple XML files into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I understand the basics of XML - HTML. Working on sport feed site, the feeds file names change all the time. For example:

- xt.222500-01.xml
- xt.222501-02.xml
- and so on...

Each file have the same content and I have setup the tables in HTML to display from XML. Traditional in JavaScript you call the file that you hard code in.

How do you call XML files that change all the time?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: You should provide some code. Then it's possible to locate and fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Very simple code using spry to get the dataset for example:

**var ds1 = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("xmlfeeds.xml", "sports-content/sports-event/team/team-metadata"**

That's about it.

Comment: More important is the question: From where do you call this line of code and what are the possibilities to dynamically insert a file name there. Especially you should have a source where to get the list of files or an actual file name.

Comment: It is called from a HTML file, nothing special. Sorry I am lost with your question.

Comment: Can you predict the pattern? If you can, you could use the following algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747622/use-javascript-to-scan-a-local-directory-and-then-update-an-anchor-tag-with-the/23747795#23747795

Comment: You need to know how the filenames are created to predict them OR you need to have a source for the list of file names.

Comment: The xml files are dumped on a server location (folder). The only common string in the file name is "xt." The feeds are a dump to the server and from there you code to what information you want on your page. Love to see if there is away just to use a "wildcard" such as ("xt.######.xml") in spry since all the tags in the xmls are the same. Is this possible? Thanks again.

Comment: To access a concrete file you can't use a wildcard. Is it possible to use a server side script? You could use this to scan the folder and then output either the filename or the file contents.

Comment: Your right, what do you recommend for server side script?